# NodeJS run tcp server on multiple ports?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to run a `tcp server` in nodejs on multiple ports?

```
var socketServer = net.createServer(function (socket) {


    socket.on('end', function () {


    });

    socket.on('error', function (error) {

    });     

    return socket;
}).listen(8080);
```

Any ideas how the above could also run on port `8888`?

Comment: Whats the problem of running it on multiple ports ? Instead of the listen(8080) use listen(process.env.PORT || 8080). Then you can start multiple servers PORT=8081 node server; PORT=8082 node server; ...

Comment: What exactly is the question: to use one instance listening on multiple ports (then see the answer below) or to have multiple (redundant) instances listening on different ports (then see the answer above). It looks like you want to achieve some sort of redundancy, but what is the actual problem you want to address?

Comment: @OlegS. I just want the clients to be able to connect to the server from different ports (sometimes the clients firewall is blocking port 8080)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best you can do is extract your connection handler and create multiple server instances:

```
function connHandler(socket) {
  socket.on('end', function() {

  });

  socket.on('error', function(error) {

  });
}

net.createServer(connHandler).listen(8080);
net.createServer(connHandler).listen(8088);
```

Comment: Sometimes getting ECONNRESET error, I am not sure why it's occurring